# Can't connect to an Azure SQL Server from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Azure database and I try to access it from PowerShell.

```
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer
```

shows my server as expected, but when I try:

```
$creds = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("LOGIN", ("PWD" | ConvertTo-SecureString –asPlainText –Force))

$serverContext = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext –ServerName "SERVER" –Credential $creds
```

I get this error message:

> New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

But if I connect from Management Studio, everything is OK.

I setup a proper firewall rule.

Does anybody know what may happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't execute query to an Azure SQL Server from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059125/cant-execute-query-to-an-azure-sql-server-from-powershell)