# Can't execute query to an Azure SQL Server from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Azure database and I try to execute the query from PowerShell.

I am using `Invoke-Sqlcmd` Command.

I get this error message:

> A network related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

But if I connect from Management Studio, everything is OK.

I setup a proper firewall rule.

Does anybody know what may happen?

Comment: Can you share details of what parameters are you passing in the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your connection string, specify TCP as the protocol like

```
tcp:mymssqlserver.database.windows.net
```

Your PowerShell may look then like:

```
$server = " tcp:mymssqlserver.database.windows.net,1433" 
$database = "master" 
$adminName = "admin@my-azure-sql" 
$adminPassword = "P4SSW0rd" 


$connectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;User ID=$adminName;Password=$adminPassword;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" 
$connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
```

Comment: In Alberto's answer, particularly important is the connection timeout setting, ensure it's 30 seconds or more.